# Add multiple colours in PrimeFaces dataTable row

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Based on drop down values, I want to show data-table row in multi-color. I followed [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml) example but its showing all rows green color or red color

My code :-

```
<p:dataTable id="empAtendanceTable"
             var="report"
             value="#{empBean.empReport}"
             rowStyleClass="#{report.status==false ? 'colored' : null} #{report.status==true ? 'error' : null}">
```

CSS :

```css
.colored {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
.error {
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

How to change the colors? I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
 <p:dataTable id="empAtendanceTable"
             var="report"
             value="#{empBean.empReport}"
             rowStyleClass="#{report.status ? 'error' : 'colored'}">
```

Comment: ,thanks for your response,its working fine based on condition.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the attribute 'background-color'. For example:

```
.colored {
   background-color: red;
   color. white;
}
```

That might help you.

Comment: Not related to the problem. The background shorthand property sets all the background properties in one declaration.

Comment: Based on condition the rows will differ .In case status is 'P' means red color and 'A' means green color .